# multiple <c:when> inside <c:choose>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am just wondering whether the below code is valid?

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${empty example2}">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>              
</c:choose>
```

Comment: It is. What's the problem you're having with it? Or did you just not bother to run it?

Comment: the 2nd <c:when> isnt getting called so I wasnt sure whether its valid to write multiple <c:when>. as you said its valid I will try changing the conditions probably.

Comment: If the 2nd isn't getting called, then the condition just don't match or was already matched before. Please ask a bit more concrete technical question than just a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 38):

In a `c:choose`,
the first *when* for which the test is true is the winner.
In the `c:choose` below,
if "first test" and "second test" are both true,
then the "Kpow" h2 will be added to the html page and the "Blammy" will not.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="first test">
    <h2>Kpow</h2>
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="second test">
    <h2>Blammy</h2>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>
  <c:when test="${empty example2}">
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
  </c:otherwise>              
</c:choose>
```

This code is nothing but

```
 switch(int i){
   case 1:
   ...
   break;
   case 2:
   ...
   break;
   default:
   ...
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its valid.  Why not just try it though?  Look up [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/reference/docs/index.html) for more info.