# JSP - <c:when>the URL is exactly this string

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm looking for a way with JSP  to check the URL and based on the result, loading a JavaScript file or not loading it.

But this is the very first time I'm working with JSP tag and I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

After some googling I put this code together:

```
<c:choose>

<c:when test=""${not pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith(‘/com’)}”> LOAD JS FILE </c:when>

<c:when test=""${not pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith(‘/womens’)}”> LOAD JS FILE </c:when>

<c:when test=""${not pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith(‘/mens’)}”> LOAD JS FILE </c:when>

<c:otherwise> DON’T LOAD JS FILE </c:otherwise>

</c:choose>
```

Basically the could is trying to achieve that if the URL is not ending with com, mens or womens a JS file should be loaded and if not the js should not be loaded.

Is my approach right?

Thanks

Comment: This is using the [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html), not simply JSP. You probably are missing the JSTL taglib. Check the link to do the settings

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is JSTL. But is my solution right? How can I combine the three conditions together?

Comment: Your question is unclear...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple <c:when> inside <c:choose>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534411/multiple-cwhen-inside-cchoose)